# Why is the defininte article sometimes left out after the word "of"?

Tags: articles

I was watching a  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nIxO-_FjOs&feature=youtu.be&t=4m55s)  where the presenter was talking about multiple meanings of some words, and then she gave an example that I am confused by, because I have no idea why *the* had been omitted. Here it goes:

> *Current* as a noun refers to the direction and speed of (the) flow of a liquid.

At first I thought it was because the word *flow* is not generally used with articles, but then I checked *the* *Oxford* *Dictionary* and saw these examples:

> ...the flow of water into the pond...
>
> The spiral wave inhibits normal waves, just as eddies in a stream inhibit the smooth flow of water.

So what would be correct if I put *the* in the first sentence? And if not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a stylistic example

> *Current* as a noun refers to the direction and speed of *(the)* flow of a liquid.

the use of "***the***" is optional the meaning will not change without its use since it is talking about *any general* flow of a liquid as opposed to

> *Current* as a noun refers to the direction and speed of **the thermal convective** flow of a liquid.